# to_string function appends zeros

Tags: c++, double, string-conversion

I'm trying to get the int part and the decimal part of a double.
This is how I've implemented this :

```
void func(double d)
{
    int intpart, decpart;
    intpart = d;
    string szDec = to_string(d);
    szDec = szDec.substr(szDec.find(".") + 1);
    decpart = stoi(szDec);
    m_iNom = intpart * decpart + 1;
    m_iDenom = decpart;
}
```

I pass to the func 0.5, the problem occurs when trying to get the decimal part as an integer.

Instead of getting 5, to_String makes szDec = "0.500000000000000"

and when using the substr() function, szDec = "0.500000"

leaving me with decpart = 500000 instead of 5.

How do I stop the to_String function and the substr function from appending zeros to the string and converting it to float ?

Comment: What's wrong with just using [std::modf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/modf)

Comment: @Cubbi Say I have 3.5, I need 3 as 5 not 3 and 0.5

Comment: How about if you have `3.1`? When you store that in a double, you get `3.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625`. Do you want `3` and `100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625` back or do you want `3` and `1`? And if you want `3` and `1`, how exactly do you want them to be calculated?

Comment: why if I store 3.1 it adds all these numbers ? And I would want the original value stored in an int so 3 and 1

Comment: An other "problem" is that `0.5` and `0.05` will lead to the same result: decimal part will be `5`.

Comment: @Jarod42 so what can I do ?

Comment: If you never store your value in a `double`, you won't get "all those numbers". If your input is a decimal fraction, keep it a decimal fraction.

Comment: @Cubbi I must store it in a double before because before this function is being called another function get's the number and pass it to this function

Comment: @Tugal.44: The proposal of Cubbi (`std::modf`) have sense. But it seems to be a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Jarod42 I don't see how modf could help me, I need the dec part as an integer

Comment: Using cubbi's answer: http://ideone.com/dXs4Rx

Comment: @Brandon but the * 10 is arbitrary, what if it's 3.10 ? or 3.100

Comment: What? 0.10 and 0.100 is the same thing afaik.. If you need to store the precision then I have no idea.. You'd have to use a string and do it all yourself.

Comment: @Brandon here lies the problem with converting to string using to_string it appends numbers which corrupts the actual input. 3.5 will make it like 3.5xxxxxxxxxx..

Comment: @Brandon To be more clear I didn't meant that I need the 0s I know for example that 0.1 = 0.10 and so on but if I had for example 0.345 the *10 is arbitrary and won't work because 0.3 != 0.345

Comment: Yes but it's hard to figure out because storing 0.5000 in a double will always be stored as either 0.5 or 0.5000000000000000. It won't be stored as 0.5000. You have to store that in a string or else use a stringstream and apply the correct precision to it.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your specific question, [std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string), is purposefully is defined to be a simple as possible and doesn't have any knobs you could turn to change the output format. For floating-point numbers, it is defined to perform the equivalent of C's `%f`, which happens to produce exactly `"0.50000"` for the input of `0.5`.

`boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(d)` would give you `"0.5"`, as would `std::ostringstream buf; buf << d; szDec = buf.str();`, or the equivalent C, but, as pointed out in the comments, if your number is something that's not representable in binary (e.g. if its 0.1 rather than 0.5), then reconstituting the optimal decimal fraction is a non-trivial algorithm.